# Static/fixed sidebar 100% height, with scrollable main and secondary content

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm building a bootstrap based website and I'd like to have a **fixed navigation** side bar **100% height** of the user's window (no scrolling) inside a container and **not to the edge of the screen**.

In addition to I'd like to have the main content scrollable as well as the secondary content scrollable independent of the main-content but again 100% height of the user's window. Almost like the way Facebook is set-up on pages. [Indetended design layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AD3NQ.jpg)

The examples I've seen by Googling all have the sidebar to the left edge which is not what I'm looking for and/or break in the layout I've been testing.

Comment: Kindly post what have you have worked on till now. Read guidelines here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: http://jsbin.com/gisegesaso/1/edit?output 

So far when applying position: fixed the div floats out of the parent container and everything else collapses leaving the navigation untop of the content. 

I'm trying to achieve something similar to the facebook layout, would the affix property be best for this?

Answer (score 3):

I made a bootsnipp for that. Check [this link](http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/0420K).

It has a fixed-no-scrollable sidebar with 100% height.
A main content scrollable.
A secondary content scrollable independent of the main-content and is 100% height.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I have updated it , now the secondary content is scrollable-indipendent

Comment: Yes, however, I'd like to have the sidebar navigation within a container, not to the edge of the screen. Is this possible with only CSS or do I need to do some jQuery?

Comment: You can try to put the fixed divs inside a container, but I'm not sure that it will work. And if you want to make it responsive , I think you have to consider a different approach